# I want to run an emmeans_test on a list with two groups in r

Tags: r

What I used on a normal data frame and what I would like to use on a list:

```
emmeans_test<-
  data %>% 
  group_by(group1) %>% 
    emmeans_test(calc ~ group2,
                 p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")
```

What I tried:

```
statistic<-lapply(list,
                       emmeans_test,
                       group_by=group1
                       calc ~ group2,
                       p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")
```

I just cannot figure out how I use two group with the emmeans test on a list?

Comment: Please post the output of `dput(data)` so we can see what your data looks like. If you have a very large dataset then please post a sample of it.

Comment: I've never heard of `emmeans_test`. What packages it in?

Comment: it is a package of rstatix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a `list`, then use `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rstatix)
out <-  map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
             group_by(group1) %>% 
             emmeans_test(calc ~ group2,
                 p.adjust.method = "bonferroni"))
```

---

Reproducible example

```
lst1  <- list(ToothGrowth, ToothGrowth)
out <-  map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
             group_by(supp) %>% 
             emmeans_test(len ~ dose, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni"))


out
[[1]]
# A tibble: 6 x 10
  supp  term  .y.   group1 group2    df statistic        p    p.adj p.adj.signif
* <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>       
1 OJ    dose  len   0.5    1         54     -5.83 3.18e- 7 9.53e- 7 ****        
2 OJ    dose  len   0.5    2         54     -7.90 1.43e-10 4.29e-10 ****        
3 OJ    dose  len   1      2         54     -2.07 4.34e- 2 1.30e- 1 ns          
4 VC    dose  len   0.5    1         54     -5.41 1.46e- 6 4.39e- 6 ****        
5 VC    dose  len   0.5    2         54    -11.2  1.13e-15 3.39e-15 ****        
6 VC    dose  len   1      2         54     -5.77 3.98e- 7 1.19e- 6 ****        

[[2]]
# A tibble: 6 x 10
  supp  term  .y.   group1 group2    df statistic        p    p.adj p.adj.signif
* <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>       
1 OJ    dose  len   0.5    1         54     -5.83 3.18e- 7 9.53e- 7 ****        
2 OJ    dose  len   0.5    2         54     -7.90 1.43e-10 4.29e-10 ****        
3 OJ    dose  len   1      2         54     -2.07 4.34e- 2 1.30e- 1 ns          
4 VC    dose  len   0.5    1         54     -5.41 1.46e- 6 4.39e- 6 ****        
5 VC    dose  len   0.5    2         54    -11.2  1.13e-15 3.39e-15 ****        
6 VC    dose  len   1      2         54     -5.77 3.98e- 7 1.19e- 6 ****
```

Comment: is there a possibility to name the output like the original filename?

Comment: @Raphael Did you meant the `list` names?

Comment: yes exactly - your suggestions worked perfectly but now every dataframe is named rstatix_test

Comment: @Raphael If you want to rename, use `names(out) <- paste0('v', seq_along(out))`

Comment: This does not work, unfortunately - dataframe is still named rstatix_test

Comment: @Raphael I didn't understand where it is named.  The output is a `list` of datasets.  Can you tell me where in the reproducible example from ToothGrowth it is shown

Comment: yes so the toothgrow has two data sets - named both dataframe - after I run the emmeans test and just look at the data - both are now named rstatix_test.

Comment: @Raphael what do you want that to be.  I guess you are looking at the attribute with `str(out)`

Comment: My list contains many different dataframes which have a unique file name like raphael_2021_04, raphael_2021_05,... 
and after the the test , all dataframes are named rstatix_test and don't have my unique file name

Comment: that they have the same name like before - in my case raphael_2021_04,...

Comment: @Raphael EVen if if you do it on a single file, the attribute will be `rstatix_test`.  It is a different attribute.  You can name the list as `names(out) <- sprintf('raphael_2021_%02d', 4:length(out))`

Comment: @Rapahel I think you are confused with `class` and object name.  The rstatix_test is a class created by the function `class(out[[1]])#
[1] "rstatix_test" "emmeans_test" "tbl_df"       "tbl"          "data.frame"#  
> class(out[[2]])
[1] "rstatix_test" "emmeans_test" "tbl_df"       "tbl"          "data.frame" `

Comment: ahh ok gotcha - yeah I was confused - thank you very much for the help!
and if you have time - one question from another topic - how can I bind one column (with only one value) of a list to every row of another list?

Comment: @Raphael you meant `bind_rows(out)` or do you need `lapply(out, function(x) transform(x, new = yournewdata$col))`

Comment: yes i used ```lapply(out, function(x) transform(x, new = yournewdata$col))``` but because they have different row numbers I get this error:
Error in data.frame(list(term = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 48, 0

Comment: @Raphael You said there is only a single observation for that column?   Also, when I said younewdata, it should be the object name you have with the column name for `col`

Comment: yes it only has one number as a value. 
Yes I used the name of the list

Comment: @Rapahel can you post that as a new question